# "could not create Vfs.Dir" in WAR project with JAR

Tags: java, jar, kepler, reflections

I have a WAR project which uses 'org.reflections' JAR, and it throws this error:

org.reflections.Reflections - could not create Vfs.Dir from url. ignoring the exception and continuing.

This only happens with this WAR, I have others that work perfectly.

The weird thing is that I downloaded Reflections project from google repository, and if I add it to my WAR build path as a project instead of adding the JAR, it works fine. The JAR is exported from this project so the version is the same.

Any ideas? I thought there may be some credential issues with the JAR, but as in other WAR is working, that is no option.

I'm using eclipse Kepler 64 bits.

Thank you!
Regards.

Comment: You need to show your code. But I suspect that you're trying to open class loader URLs as file system object when this is not always the case in a deployed application.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that JAVAASSIST library is needed by org.reflections, although the error was not shown.

Comment: That's probably a good excuse to switch to a good build system that does not ignore transitive dependencies. And usually your log file should show that error - check them out.